# Как в питон добавить значение в список

Tags: python

```
documents = [
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
  ]
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
  }




def create_user(type, side):
  n_pass = input()
  t_pass = input()
  n_user = input()
  s_user = int(input)
  q = {'number': n_pass, 'type' : t_pass, 'name' : n_user}
  type.append(q)
  return type


print(create_user(documents, directories))
```

По заданию надо написать функцию, которая будет создавать юзера по введенным значениям в `documents` по переменным `n_pass = input()`,  `t_pass  = input()`, `n_user = input()`  - это я сделал. А ещё он должен брать ключ 'number' и ложить на полку которую юзер  укажет в переменной  `s_user = int(input)`. То есть при добавлении в `documents`. мы ввели `number = 222`, после этого берем  `number = 222` и кладем в значение той полки что указана в `s_user = int(input)`. Я это четко понимаю,
\ но как это реализовать для меня проблема

Comment: Ну точно так же через `append`, просто сообразить, как туда доступиться - к нужному элементу словаря. И не используйте имя `type` для переменной - это встроенная функция питона.

Comment: Спасибо, я вроде сделал но тперь столкнулся с такой ошибкой TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: скобки забыли, нужно `int(input())`

Comment: Пасиб, не заметил

Answer (score 1):

В Python значения в список можно добавить при помощи встроенной функции **append**. К примеру у нас есть у нас есть переменная **breakfest** (с английского - завтрак) и оно является списком. Изначально, наш лист будет иметь такие значения:

```
# Создаем список и добавляем туда изначальные значения.
breakfest = ['Чай', 'Кофе', 'Творог', 'Йогурт']
```

Теперь, мы хотим добавить объект **"Бутерброд"** в наш список. Для этого в Python есть функция **append** речь о которой уже шла выше. Ее мы и будем использовать.

```
# Добавляем наш бутерброд в список.
breakfest.append('Бутерброд')
```

А дальше уже что вам нужно то и делаете со списком. Можем, например, его вывести в консоль.

```
# Выводим список в консоль.
print(breakfest)
```

Результат же будет таков:

```
['Чай', 'Кофе', 'Творог', 'Йогурт', 'Бутерброд']
```

Можем вывести по отдельности каждый элемент из списка:

```
# Выводим каждый элемент из списка.
print('Список - что у нас есть на завтрак:')
for item in breakfest: # Переменная item будет в качестве одно из элементов из списка.
    print(item) # Выводим наш элемент
```

```
Список - что у нас есть на завтрак:
Чай
Кофе
Творог
Йогурт
Бутерброд
```

Вот так легко работать со списками в Python!

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы что-то добавить в список - нужно использовать метод [append](https://pythonstart.ru/list/append-extend-python)

Например:

```
list.append(variable) #Вместо variable(в переводе с английского переменная) можно использовать и числа и строки
```